# php simple socket_listen

Tags: php, sockets

I have the following :

```
$host = "192.168.0.117";
$port = 777;

set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not createsocket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
```

The variable `result` gives me an error:

> unable to listen on socket [0]: An invalid argument was supplied

Comment: You should probably use socket streams instead. Look up `stream_socket_server`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a socket to (address, port) pair first and only then call listen on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$host = '192.168.0.117';
$port = '777';

set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($socket, $adddress, $port) or die("Could not connect");
socket_listen($socket);

$client_connection = socket_accept($socket);
$input = socket_read($client_connection, 1024);

$output = ereg_replace('[\t\n\r]','', $input).chr(0);

//display output
socket_write($client_connection, $output);

socket_close($client_connection);
socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: now i got this error: 
unable to bind address [0]: Only one usage of each socket address

Comment: That means you need to use a different port, as a different program or service is set to run on port 777 on your machine already.

Comment: Look here http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml then choose a higher numbered port that is not in use out of this list. You can also check your systems used ports to make sure that any applications installed aren't using the one you're trying to use.